# Session expire on browser closing in Odoo

Tags: python, session, odoo, session-cookies, expired-sessions

In Odoo 10, how can I delete or expire the session on the browser window closing.

Currently the session does not expire until I logout.

I got a solution for session expire on time out. But that's not required for me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is about helping people with their code, not provide entire applications.

Comment: @damienc I am new to odoo. So I am not familiar with it. I got a solution for session expire on time out. But that's not required for me.